# Trigger method with click and drag (Angular)

Tags: angular, click, drag

I have a table, where I'd like users to be able to trigger a method with a click and drag across multiple cells (i.e., changing background color of cells that were clicked/dragged over).

I want to create this in Angular.

When I use the click method, it only triggers on the cell that is first clicked, not any other cells where the mouse is down (i.e., I have to click every cell to highlight or unhighlight).

It should look like this:
[image]

Below is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dpmki)

Component:

```
<table>
  <TR>
    <TD *ngFor="let b of colCount" 
        (click)="b.highlight = !b.highlight" 
        [class.highlight]="b.highlight"
    ></TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

TS:

```
 colCount = [{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true}]

  select(b) {
    console.log(b)
    b.highlight = !b.highlight
  }
```

CSS:

```
td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 20px !important;
 height: 20px !important;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use the events `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup` to set this up. I recommend setting a flag in the component `mouseIsDown` when `mousedown` happens, then changing the highlight in `mousemove` when the flag is true, and then unsetting the flag in `mouseup`.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there an example of this that you have seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just checks if the mouse is down and enters the next block.

Check this stackblitz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-55xflc

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let b of colCount" 
        (mousedown)="mousedown(b)" 
        (mouseover)="mouseover(b)"
        (window:mouseup)="mouseup()"
        [class.highlight]="b.highlight"
    ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS

```
down: boolean = false

colCount = [{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true},{highlight: true}]

mousedown(b) {
  this.down = true
  if (this.down) {
    b.highlight = !b.highlight
  }
}

mouseover(b) {
  if (this.down) {
    b.highlight = !b.highlight
  }
}

mouseup() {
  this.down = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you are looking for the various `mouse` events, something like this should probably do the trick.

You might need to tweak it a little bit to make sure it works exactly as you want, but this should be a good starting point.

```
<table>
  <TR>
    <TD *ngFor="let b of colCount"
        (click)="b.highlight = !b.highlight"
        (mousedown)="mouseIsDown = true"
        (mouseup)="mouseIsDown = false"
        (mouseleave)="mouseIsDown ? b.highlight = !b.highlight : null"
        [class.highlight]="b.highlight"
    ></TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

---

```
export class Component {
  mouseIsDown = false;
  ...
}
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rsrtx)